# Как ограничить общий объем прикрепляемых файлов в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

На портале есть  форма обратной связи, к которой прикручен компонент main.file.input, который позволяет прикреплять файлы. Последнее время люди стали грузить очень много файлов в следствии чего  сообщение получается очень тяжелым и почтовик просто отказывается его отправлять. Ограничение веса на каждый файл в настройках компонента есть, а вот общего размера файлов почему то нет. Как можно собственноручно такое ограничение туда дописать? Или может есть какие либо другие способы?

Answer (score 2):

Можно, например, скопировать себе шаблон компонента и добавить свои проверки в скрипт загрузки. Например, взять шаблон drag_n_drop и в файле script.js поправить функцию window.BlogBFileDialogUploader.prototype.CallSubmit

Comment: Благодарю, будем пробовать

Comment: Ну вообщем дня три ковырял этот скрипт, так ничего и не вышло, получилось только навещать проверку на один файл, на все почему то не выходит